# How can I use Microsoft installer (msi) to group JBoss and Postgres database and make an .exe file?

Tags: postgresql, jboss, windows-installer, windows-authentication

I'm completely new to Microsoft installer and have installed advinst.msi, and I'm wondering how to use it.

I have to group  **Jboss** where my Java application is deployed and **postgres** database and want to create an .exe file and deploy it to clients windows system.

Where the client can run the .exe file and start the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jboss package you can add a as [a prerequisite](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites). This will make Advanced Installer to install it when you install your application, see the link from above.

To deploy a database you have two options. Either you execute an SQL script that creates and populates it, as in this [SQL scripts execution tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-sql.html), or you deploy directly the binary files of your database, by placing them in the target folder from Files and Folders page, as you do with a normal file. The second option will make your installer to copy the files into the desired folder upon installation, so you database manager/explorer can access it.

To have all this bundled into a single executable you need to go to Media page and set the package output type to "Single setup EXE". From there you can also customize the EXE name, icon and output folder.

Comment: :- Thank u so much for answer ... According to answer i'm able to create a .exe file and after clicking to .exe file ,iam able to copy jboss and postgres database to desired loation . But how can i start my jboss and postgres?
Do i've to need any service that can start them or need any batch file that should run jst before completion of installation process?
please suggest

Comment: From what I see you are deploying the installers for jboss and postgress and need to launch them, one by one. For this please use the prerequisites support, analyze carefully that part of the tutorial. You can also find similar users doing the same thing on Advanced Installer forums, www.advancedinstaller.com/forums

Comment: thanx for your valuable answer ... i'm able to copy my jboss and postgres to a derired location and even able to start batch file just before the completion process of .exe file. I'm thinking to write script for starting jboss and postgres..but i'm wondering that is it a  good way or should i try for service option advanced  installer?

Comment: If these are standard Windows services than you can try adding two control operations, in Services page (http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/service-control-properties.html) to start/stop them. A custom action can also work very good, I recommend C++ or C# Dll, scripts are not reliable.